# ECS Task Health and metrics vanished while container are still up

Tags: devops, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

[image]

The ECS containers were initially operational, but after a brief period, the metrics vanished. Initially, API calls were functioning correctly, but around half an hour later, we began encountering 504 errors at the ALB, indicating that the containers were no longer responsive.

How did this occur? Despite all the containers being in a running state, the AWS health dashboard displayed no data during that timeframe.

It happened again after a minute!!
[image]

Comment: Sounds like some sort of outage inside the AWS infrastructure that Amazon didn't bother to update on the health dashboard.